# Click Close Div, Set Cookie, Check Cookie Exists, If so Don't Show Div

Tags: javascript, cookies

The title explains it all. I haven't actually been able to find this particular code example anywhere on the web that will make it work as simply as my posted script almost does.

Can you help me figure out why my script displays the div, twice, sometimes 3 times before finally not displaying after the cookie has been set?

I've checked after loading the site once - the cookie gets set, but upon clicking on another page, the display box (div) still shows up. After a few more "I Accept" clicks, it finally doesn't show again.

I'd like to figure out why it takes more than 1 click to stay closed. Is my code highly inefficient? Is it impossible to keep a function like this as simple as my code is below?

Here is my code

Body onload:

```
<body onload="cookiefunction()"
```

Javascript that checks if cookie exists and if not display the div, and if so don't display the div:

```
function cookiefunction() {

if (document.cookie.indexOf("acceptterms") >= 0) { 
    document.getElementById("notice").style.display = "none";
     } else {
        document.getElementById("notice").style.display = "block"; 
    }
}
```

Code that sets the cookie once the I Accept link is clicked

```
function closediv() {
    document.getElementById("notice").style.display ="none";
    document.cookie = "acceptterms=yes; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2023 12:00:00 UTC";
 }
```

The div that should display:none if the I accept is clicked

```
<div id="notice" style="display:none;">
<a href="#" id="close" onclick="closediv()">I Accept Terms</a>
</div>
```

Could it be some code I have in .htaccess related to caching that is causing this issue?

Comment: Why do you have `window.parent`? Are you trying to do this in a frame?

Comment: I'm not slightly perfect with JS so I'm hacking along based on script references I find. Do you think window.parent is affecting my script this way?

Comment: I removed window,parent, and it appears to be working as it should, in Chrome. In FireFox, I have to "accept" 2 or more times, then it stops displaying on a new page load, why?

Comment: any advice on optimizing this code?